# Christmas turkey help (mostly organization)

Tags: turkey, organization

We are receiving the family at my parent's house for Christmas lunch at around 2pm; GF and I are doing all of the cooking.

The turkey is fresh about 12lb.

I think it should take about 4 hours and some resting time.

We will have stuffing on the side.

I was thinking of 3 scenarios.

1. Completely cook the turkey the day before, slice it and re-heat on the day. my fear is that it will be dry and over cooked after re-heating.
2. start cooking the turkey at my home early on Christmas, and just bring it to my parent's home (15 mins by car) and finish it up there (for the last hour+resting)
3. Prepare the turkey the day before and bring it uncooked at my parent's place the day before so they can put it in the oven in the morning.

I will push the #2 plan with my GF.

Any other suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for any other options.

I bet you could cook it all the way and safely rest it in a cooler (acting as a warmer).

Finishing in another kitchen is a hassle.  This leaves the oven open for other stuff.